# How can I split selenium test classes from selenium framework?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, web-testing, design-principles

I am currently working at my job on GUI web pages automation using selenium via Java in Intellij. We have few product development teams, where one is maintaining&developing continuously selenium framework and theirs tests. Other teams grabbed selenium framework few months ago and developed their own tests, now they are continuing to develop tests only. All teams uses Git/Gerrit and Jenkins for continues integration. The issue for me is that two teams mentioned above, uses framework which is outdated now. My concern now is;

Is there a way to keep framework(together with Page Object classes) as a separate project, and then have separate projects, per each team, with test classes only?

I have tried to ask google first, but unfortunately did not find anything.

Comment: Are the selenium tests packaged with the applications?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are asking for the following 3 projects:

1. PageObject common library (based upon Selenium)
2. Team #1 test cases using common library + Selenium version Y
3. Team #2 test cases using common library + Selenium version X

Each project would be independent of one another and follow simple project dependency rules: interfaces for communication between package and no shared usage of implementation classes.

Each Selenium test project would be maintained entirely independent from the other. The PageObjects common library would be the synchronization point and have a defined API for application navigation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Let me rephrase my goal a little bit:

a) What I would like to have is one common git repository with selenium framework for all three teams...
b) 3 other repositories with tests only(one for each team), which will be using common framework